# I can suspend the computer but how do I "un-suspend" it?

Tags: suspend, pantheon, release-jolnir

My machine is a Gigabyte Brix S with an AMD Ryzen 7-4800U Processor and a pair of LG 60cm displays. Selecting suspend in the drop-down at the r/h end of the Wingpanel instantly puts it to sleep but when I want to resume using it I can find no combination of keys or mouse clicks (Apple wired keyboard and old Targus wired mouse) which wakes it.

I have to switch off and back on and log in in the usual way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to press the Control key. That brings the computer out of sleep/suspension in a few seconds.